# Why does the author use ‘would’ in “I would kill him inchmeal just now”?

Tags: meaning-in-context, conditionals, will-would

> *I am a sanguinary murderer of time, and **would** kill him inchmeal just now. But the snake is vital*.

I'm confused because of "just now". Doesn't that mean 'a short while ago'? If so, why is there 'would'?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. See also [ell.se] Good Luck.

Comment: *Would* indicates potentiality, conditionality, wishfulness etc; *just now* means right at this moment. In any case, I'm flagging this as off-topic ("belongs on ELL"). Hi AMA, you may not be aware that our other site [ell.se] is the best place to look for answers on English questions that a fluent speaker would find trivial. If you have a question for ELL, be sure to read their guidance on [what you can ask](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). :-)

Comment: Are you asking about *would* or *just now*? It's not clear. The title of your question says one thing but the body of your question, although referring to the one, mentions both. Why do you think there would be a problem using both together? (Even if *just now* did mean *a short while ago*, why do you think that *would* is misplaced?)

Answer (score 1):

From a letter by Charles Lamb (1775-1834). As well as "a short while ago", "just now" can also mean "at present or at this moment", which would fit the context. This useage is very common in Scottish speech.

> a. very short time ago
>   b. at this moment
>   c. (South Africa informal) in a little while

[Just now (Collins Dictionary)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/just-now)

Answer (score 0):

In the above context "would" implies a hypothetical scenario.  And, as typical, the usage above suggests a condition that argues against this hypothetical outcome.